# Citing a Paper and a Lemma in Latex

Tags: citing

I am using *thebibliography* environment to list the reference papers. Currently I am citing a paper like this [1] (Paper number within square brackets). What I would like to have is [1, Lemma 1] (Paper number and Lemma number within square brackets). I searched for solutions and all the solutions involve biblatex or bibtex. Is this possible with *thebibliography* environment? I prefer *thebibliography* environment because I want a single file for uploading. Thanks in advance.

This is how the references are given.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{ref1} Name of Paper 1 
\bibitem{ref2} Name of Paper 2
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Incidentally, the claim "I prefer [the] `thebibliography` environment because I want a single file for uploading" contains a *non sequitur*. BibTeX and biblatex/biber both build an external file (with extension .bbl) to contain the formatted bibliographic entries. Once you're satisfied that the bibliography is fine, there is nothing to stop you (or anyone else) from copying the contents of the bbl file into the main tex file and deleting the `\bibliography` and `\printbibliography` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't `\cite[]{}` do the job?

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

See \cite[lemma 1]{foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{foo}
  Foo \& Bar,
  {\em Treaty of mathematics},
  2021

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.